# TCL : Need information Regarding Regular expression in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

1) My string is below

```
% set a {
    absdsdgfg
    dsdgsdg
    sdgsdgsd
    asdas192.168.2.1
    asdfsdf
    sdfsdf
    10.10.10.1
}
absdsdgfg
dsdgsdg
sdgsdgsd
asdas192.168.2.1
asdfsdf
sdfsdf
10.10.10.1
```

2)  Regular expression is

```
% regexp {.*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*} $a -> ip
1
```

3) Output

```
% set ip
0.10.10.1    
%
```

In the Step Number - 3 I am getting the output as `0.10.10.1` . Why I am missing `1` here? It is a number it should match with `\d`, but why it is maching with `(.*)`.

Answer (score 4):

The first `.*` is eating the `1`.

To avoid this from happening, you can use a lazy version of `.*` that is: `.*?`

The reason behind is is that the first `.*` first matches everything until the end of the string and then goes back one character at a time checking for the other characters which are yet to be matched by the regex.

Once it has gone back to the point before the 0 here: `0.10.10.1`, the last part of the regex matches (meaning it won't go back more than that) and the regex returns a successful match.

And this is what goes into the captured group, you named `ip`.

The `.*?` however will match as little as possible and will get `192.168.2.1`. If you want to get `10.10.10.1`, use this regex:

```
regexp {.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s*$} $a -> ip
```

Or you can have it shorter:

```
regexp {.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s*$} $a -> ip
```

And actually, the `.*?` is not even needed here:

```
regexp {(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s*$} $a -> ip
```

Comment: what does this ?: mean in  this (?:\.\d+) . what is the execution flow in the regexp {\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$} $a ip . Can you Please explain me in more detailed .

Comment: @user2746819 This is a non-capture group, and is being used for grouping so that you can do the repeat `{3}`. `\d+(?:\.\d+){3}` is 1 or more digits, followed by (a period and one or more digits) repeated 3 times. The `$` indicates the end of the string.

Comment: That counted repetition doesn't really add anything much here. I'd go with just `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+` if I could (except it matches earlier in the sample too)…

Answer (score 0):

For a string 
 set a {
    absdsdgfg
    dsdgsdg
    sdgsdgsd
    asdas192.168.2.1
    asdfsdf
    sdfsdf
    10.10.10.1
 }
Use a Regular Expression : 
          % regexp -all {(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)} $a ip
          %puts "$ip"
            10.10.10.1